# How to include anchors to elements placed in a different template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have the following list in a `sidebar.html` partial:

```
<div id="players">...</div>
<div ng-include="'partials/courts.html'"></div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#players">Players</a></li>
  <li><a href="#courts">Courts</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the `div#courts` is not in `sidebar.html` but in `partials/courts.html`:

```
// partials/courts.html
<div id="courts">...</div>
```

How can I refer to `div#courts` from the list in `sidebar.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

> When called, it scrolls to the element related to the specified hash
>   or (if omitted) to the current value of $location.hash(), according to
>   the rules specified in the HTML5 spec.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

---

Add this in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {

   $scope.scroll = function(id) {
      $location.hash(id);
      $anchorScroll();
   }

});
```

Change the links to include `ng-click="scroll('<element id>')`:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="scroll('players')">Players</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="scroll('courts')">Courts</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Online Demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/54O1NAy3Z7bguRXeSCsO?p=preview**

Comment: Do I need to download a dependency? Because it's not working for me.

Comment: add in your controller `$location` and `$anchorScroll` dependencies (they are built in)

Comment: Just to clarify. What's not working for me is a `scrollspy` class I am using from the MaterializeCSS framework.